# Scala Json nested

Tags: json, scala

Could any one help me how I can achieve the below Json using scala. Note that the col_1 thru Col_6 are based on my input. Means there might be one col or two col or 3 col.. etc.. in this Json.

Below is the desired output

```
{
  "size" : value,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        { "match": {"col_1": "value"} },
        { "match": {"col_2": "value"} },
        { "match": {"col_3": "value"} },
        { "match": {"col_4": "value"} },
        { "match": {"col_5": "value"} },
        { "match": {"col_6": "value"} },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: pls discard `enter code here` (not sure how it came).

Comment: You can edit it and remove the enter code here.

Comment: What is your desired output. Please elaborate question.

Comment: correct Json format:

Comment: The Json which I posted is the desired output using Scala

Comment: what library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could have used lift-json in these cases. lift-json is easy to implement and understand.

I am including all the steps:

1. Include in build.sbt (Change this as per maven etc.)

   "net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.11" % "2.6.2"
2. Import and implement (Reduce number of variables as this is for example purpose)

   ```
   import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
   import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write 

   case class Must(`match`: Map[String, String])
   case class Bool(must: List[Must])
   case class Query(bool: Bool)
   case class Json(size: String, query: Query)


    implicit val format = DefaultFormats

    val colList = List("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "col5")
    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Must]
    for (col <- colList) {
      listBuffer += Must(Map(col -> "value"))
    }
   val mustList = listBuffer.toList

    /** mustList will look like this:
       val mustList = List(Must(
                               Map("col_1" -> "value")
                               ))

    */
   val v = write(Json("value", Query(Bool(mustList))))
   println(v)
   ```
3. This will produce output similar to:

   > {   "size": "value",   "query": {
   >       "bool": {
   >         "must": [
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col_1": "value"
   >             }
   >           },
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col_2": "value"
   >             }
   >           },
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col_3": "value"
   >             }
   >           },
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col_4": "value"
   >             }
   >           },
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col5": "value"
   >             }
   >           },
   >           {
   >             "match": {
   >               "col_6": "value"
   >             }
   >           }
   >         ]
   >       }   } }

Comment: Thanks for the complete code. I am new to scala, sorry if this is a basic one. I am getting error as not found: type Must in the following line ==> val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Must] . Also getting error in the line ==> val v = write(Json("value", Query(Bool(mustList))))... say Json, Bool and Query not found

Comment: @paul Yeah sure I can see that no problem I am editing code again for case classes and If your problem gets resolved then do mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see little issue in the format after adding the case class.  Here is the details. My list should be dynamic so I tested with val colList = List("col1", "col2")

    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Must]
    for (col <- colList) {
      listBuffer += Must(Map("col1" -> "PAUL", "col2" -> "Barb"))
    }

Comment: Thank you so much. I see little issue in the format after adding the case class.  Here is the details. My list should be dynamic so I tested with val colList = List("col1", "col2")

    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Must]
    for (col <- colList) {
      listBuffer += Must(Map("col1" -> "PAUL", "col2" -> "Barb"))
    }   now I see the output like this ==>         {"size":"20","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":[{"_1":"col1","_2":"PAUL"},{"_1":"col2","_2":"Barb"}]},{"match":[{"_1":"col1","_2":"PAUL"},{"_1":"col2","_2":"Barb"}]}]}}}   continuation in my next comment.

Comment: but I would like to have like this. {
  "size": "20",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "col1": "PAUL"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "col2": "Barb"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Note: There is no change from my original request and my original desired result stay as it is

Comment: It is my bad, I tested your code with my existing program which produced different result. I tested separately and it is working perfect. Thank you so much. when I run in Eclipse it is producing the desired result but in the cluster it is producing lift web Json not found exception. I am using Scala 2.11.0 and "net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.11" % "2.6.2".

Comment: Note: I am using Spark-submit in Mapr cluster. Below is the error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/liftweb/json/Formats

Comment: My issue is resolved now. The lift-json_2.11 jar was not in my cluster which resulted this issue. so I copied the Jar and given the class path in my spark submit and it worked perfect.  here is the additional parameter in my spark-submit                   --driver-class-path /mapr/xxx/xxxx/xx/lift-json_2.11-2.6.2.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/mapr/xxx/xxxx/xx/lift-json_2.11-2.6.2.jar

Comment: Hey @paul Has your issue resolved ?? Do you need any help ?

Comment: Very well. Good to hear.